# Spring 3 MVC and Multiparts

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipart

I am using Spring 3's MVC framework, primarily just for the annotations.

As an example, the user will upload something like:

```
------------------------------6526f0c735cd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

[
  {
    "someField":"foo",
    "someNestedObject":{
      "someDeeperField":"bar",
      "someResourceField":"25f33030-12ed-4636-b5f7-759d27c40f08"
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
]

------------------------------6526f0c735cd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="25f33030-12ed-4636-b5f7-759d27c40f08"; filename="some.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<Binary Data>
```

Note that the name of the second part is part of the data in the first part. Then my code looks like:

```
@RequestMapping("test")
public static @ResponseBody void test(
    @RequestParam("data") final String data,
    final HttpServletRequest request)
    throws Exception {

    System.out.println(request.getParts());
}
```

It prints out an empty list because Spring has already consumed the Parts InputStream for its own processing. This is because I am using a MultipartResolver, which is something I need.

My problem is that, I still need access to the parts. I cannot use the `@RequestPart` annotation because I won't know the names of the parts until after I have processed the `data` part. I need to be able to ask Spring for one of the parts programmatically as opposed to as an argument to the function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just found out that you can have a parameter like `@RequestParam final Map<String, String> params`, which is really nice. Unfortunately, you cannot do `@RequestPart final Map<String, InputStream> parts`.

Comment: You should probably add your comment as an answer and accept it. The approach does look good.

Comment: I think you misread it, or I was not clear. `@RequestPart final Map<String, InputStream> parts` does _not_ work. And the `@RequestParam final Map<String, String> params` does not give me access to the parts.

Comment: Ah, okay, yes I misunderstood your comment. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I am using `@RequestPart("media") final List<MultipartFile> media`. All parts that are binary (media) data have the name "media", and their filename is their unique identifier.

I still like `@RequestPart final Map<String, MultipartFile> media`, but I will concede that it is really just syntactic sugar at this point.